# java.sql.ResultSet.next() description

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I've a question about the same point in the next(), previous() & absolute()
in these boolean methods

**Does** the position of the cursor change if it returns false
for example:
1)Incase of next():

```
ResultSet rs = new Result();
    while (rs.next())
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
    rs.next(); // it will return false but will the cursor be after after last ?!
```

2)Incase of absolute():

```
ResultSet rs = new Result();
    rs.absolute(15);    //assuming I've only 10 rows it will return false but will the cursor be advanced ?
```

if the answer is that they change only when they return true so why there is a method gets me out of the range of rows as afterLast() ?

BTW I've checked java docs and I didn't found an answer to my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`afterLast()` can be used to forcefully exhaust a `RestulSet`. Another usage, if the `ResultSet` is scroallable, is to iterate over it backwards with the `previous()` method:

```
ResultSet rs = ...;
rs.afterLast();
while (rs.previous()) {
    // do something.
}
```

Admittedly, I can't fathom any **good** reason to do this, but it's doable.

EDIT:
With regard to the question what will happen if you call `next()` on a `ResultSet` that's already positioned after the last row - it depends on the implementation of the JDBC driver. Some drivers just silently return `false` and do not change the state of the `ResultSet`, while some may fail the call with an `SQLException`. More specifically, do quote the documentation:

> If the result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, it is vendor specified whether their JDBC driver implementation will return false or throw an SQLException on a subsequent call to next.

Comment: but you haven't answered the main question which appears in comments of the code ?

Comment: It was commented out ;-) On a more serious note - see my edit.

Comment: @IslamSalah The moral of that is not to hide your main question in comments in the code. Or indeed any question.